# Drop down list selectors JQUERY

Tags: jquery, list, each

I'm trying to create a jQuery drop-down script that will be efficient and minimal. 
I need a way to associate a couple of uls with a li and reference this in an each loop.
Think of each of the clickable li titles as a cluster and the 'child' ul's under them are part of this too.

I want to write a piece of efficient code, using an each loop to iterate through each of the clickable lis and expand the sublist uls associated with it.
The problem is I need to know how to associate these sublist uls with the parent li in a way that can be referenced in an each loop. No standard jquery selectors can really help me because the sublist uls are not REALLY children of the li.

HTML and Jquery attempt below. Please Help

```
<ul>
        <li class='tier1'>This is what I want to click</li>
            <ul (#1)>
                <li>I want this to drop down</li>

            </ul>
                             <ul>
                <li  id="gap">I want these to drop down</li>

            </ul>
       <li class='tier1'>Another clickable title</li>
            <ul>
                <li  id="gap">I dont want this to drop down when I click the li at the top of this markup</li>

            </ul>
</ul>
```

My problem is that the ul (#1) that i want to slideToggle when I click the the li above it, is not quite a child.

So I made the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tier1').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid due to nesting ULs between LIs.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle and share the link. We are missing some elements (the one that uses the .tier1 class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/D29mQ/2/

You have some errors in your markup. A `ul` cannot be a direct descendent of a `ul`, but can be a direct descendent of a `li`. I have added a `hide()` on the `ul`'s within the li.drawer, so that the content is not hidden if javascript is disabled (I would not recommend hiding these with css).

```
<ul>
<li>
    <p class='handle'>This is what I want to click</p>
    <ul  class='drawer'>
        <li>
            <p class='handle'>This has a drawer too!</p>
            <ul  class='drawer'>
            <li>I want this to drop down</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul  class='drawer'>
        <li>I want these to drop down</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <p class='handle'>This is what I want to click</p>
    <ul  class='drawer'>
        <li>I want this to drop down</li>
    </ul>
    <ul  class='drawer'>
        <li>I want these to drop down</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<div>
    <p class='handle'>Here is an example using a wrapper div and paragraph tags.</p>
    <p  class='drawer'>
        I want this to drop down
    </p>
    <p  class='drawer'>
        I want these to drop down
    </p>
</div>
```

and the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.drawer').hide();
  $('.handle').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().not(this).slideToggle('slow');        
  });
});
```

Comment: I have something similar to this. I have a working solution, but the code is rather long. Instead of iterating ever cluster name and what follows it, I want to create simple code that will loop through and iterate for me

Comment: also, please read my answer. when i say you have errors in your markup, that means the html code you have written is invalid and will not function properly when you try to manipulate it with jquery or javascript

Comment: I have chosen yours as the best answer because it is simple code to do what I need and allows for multiple tiers.
Can you explain the last line of code to me?
the $(this).parent().children().not(this).slideToggle(); ?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem may be that in your provided HTML there is nothing with the "tier1" class. You also don't need an `.each()` function, as you can just attach the click function to the class:

```
$('.tier1').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Your HTML was also invalid, you can't have UL's nested in UL's. Fixed version:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tier1">This is what I want to click
        <ul>
            <li>I want this to drop down</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li  id="gap">I want these to drop down</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tier1">Another clickable title
        <ul>
            <li id="gap">I dont want this to drop down when I click the li at the top of this markup</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You'll also want some CSS to hide the children before the click:

```
ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
```

Working demo in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xjYy/).

Comment: How can I effectlively create a collapsible lists without nesting lists? Also, you don't have an end tag for a the clickable li items. Is this alright? Edit. I also edited the code above. tried to post the actual code for this project, but it doesn't render correctly in jsfiddle. At least, it doesn't render the way it does currently in a browser.

Comment: There is an end tag. They way they're structured is `<li><ul><li></li></ul></li>` -- note the `ul` INSIDE of the first `li`. As for creating a collapsable list without nesting, you'll have to be more specific on what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Actually. I have a third tier, so I need to be able to click on what dropped down without it toggling back.

Comment: Modified the code to work with more tiers: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj5Pe/. The structure of the HTML is different, and the jQuery was changed to reflect it.

Comment: The problem with your code is that I have a third tier of information that I need to be able to click on. If I click on it, it is part of the parent li, which will just collapse the list.

Comment: The fiddle I linked to allows a 3rd tier with code modifications. For a little more clarity, see this fiddle (click on the first item, then the second item in that list to see the 3rd item): http://jsfiddle.net/Cj5Pe/1/